# Dropdown list not showing name values

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to show a list of names to select from using a drop down list in angular. It is clearly a drop down list but the names in my array are not showing up. I feel like this might be a small fix and i am just missing it, I am relatively new to Angular, Please help!

[This is the html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCLGW.jpg)

[This is the ts page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ObnE.jpg)

HTML page///

```
<div class="container">
  <div [hidden]="submitted">
    <h1>Student Form</h1>
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #StudentForm="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Course Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Coursename"
               required
               [(ngModel)]="model.Coursename" name="Coursename"
               #inputname="ngModel"  required required minlength= "10" maxlength="50">
        <div *ngIf="Coursename.invalid && (inputCourseName.dirty || inputCoursename.touched)"
             class="alert alert-danger">
          Course Name is required
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="CourseScore">Course Score</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CourseScore"
               [(ngModel)]="model.score" name="CourseScore">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Studentname">Student Name</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="Studentname"
                required
                [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="Studentname"
                #name="ngModel">
          <option *ngFor="let name of names" [value]="name">{{name}}</option>
        </select>
        <div *ngIf="Studentname.invalid || Studentname.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
          Student Name is required
        </div>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!StudentForm.form.valid">Submit</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="newStudent(); StudentForm.reset()">Clear</button>
      <i>with</i> reset

      &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="newStudent()">New Student</button>
      <i>without</i> reset
```

.ts page///

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Student } from '../shared/student';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-student-form',
  templateUrl: './student-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./student-form.component.css']
})
export class StudentFormComponent implements OnInit {

  Student: StudentFormComponent
  names = ['Amritha Nair', 'Sarah Smith',
  'Paul Hughman', 'Isabelle Simpkins', 'Sabrina Raj'];

  model = new Student();

  submitted = false;

  onSubmit() { this.submitted = true; }

  get diagnostic() { return JSON.stringify(this.model); }

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.model=new Student();
  }

  cancel(): void {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('home');
  }

}
```

Comment: Please post your code here on text rather than adding a screenshot of the code.

Comment: What is Studentname? Can you open developer console? You are getting error thats why your select is empty

Comment: Copy the code from wherever you have it and add it to your question by putting triple backticks around it.

Comment: Please see this from angular official docs. It looks like your syntax for ngModel is not correct. https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#using-select-controls-in-a-template-driven-form

Comment: I have copied the code and edited my question

Comment: I guess, this will not work: `Student: StudentFormComponent
  names = [...];`, it should be something like `names: Student [] = [...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a clear error in the console which should help you.

Change reference name to `#studentName` instead of `#name`

```
<select class="form-control" id="Studentname"
                required
                [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="Studentname"
                #Studentname="ngModel">
 <option *ngFor="let name of names" [value]="name">{{name}}</option>
</select>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-error-select-ref?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: That still doesn't show the name values from my array in the drop down list

Comment: Did you take some time to check the demo link?

Comment: yes, the code in the demo and mine are the exact same

Comment: Do you see any other errors in your console? Change the reference name appropriately for all your form elements. I have just shown one change. `#inputname` should be changed to `Coursename`